# Array unique by comparing a node of an item

Tags: php

I want to remove duplicated objects of an array of objects. For example, I got an array like this one :

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'object_id' => string '13' (length=2)
      public 'object_data' => float 5
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'object_id' => string '13' (length=2)
      public 'object_data' => float 5
      public 'random_data' => float 15
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'object_id' => string '14' (length=2)
      public 'object_data' => float 25
      public 'random_data' => float 35
```

I was using the function

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

to remove the duplicated objects but those I have above are not identical, so I was wondering if it is possible to remove those duplicated according to an specific node "**object_id**" instead of comparing the full object?

Is that posible ?

Also in the case of getting 2 similar objects like above, can I keep the one with the "**random_data**" on it ?

Should I use a loop and traverse all the objects or is there any way to do it with a function like *array_unique*?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your array of objects */ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $input as $obj ) {
  $id = $obj->object_id;
  if ( !isset($output[$id]) ) {
    $output[$id] = array();
  }

  $output[$id] = (object) array_merge((array) $output[$id], (array) $obj);
}
```